# Undefined object method call inside the same defined object

Tags: javascript, browser, frontend, undefined

I have this following scenario:

I have a JS (parent) class that constructs/creates two other classes. The parent class is attached to window object on the client side (browser). My issue is a call in the following manner:

`window.parent.create({data: window.parent.utility.getId()})`

in rare occasions, like one in 200 or one in 1000 I get an error that says can't call `utility` of undefined!

this means that the `parent` class is undefined! but if it was undefined how did it even make a call to `window.parent.create()` ?

what could possibly allow `parent` to be defined on the first call then make it undefined in the inner call?

Comment: What exactly is the error message? "*can't call utility of undefined*" can't be it, since you're calling `getId` not `utility`.

Comment: @Bergi this is why I said it is confusing me. It is saying that `parent` is being undefined, so the call to `utility` can't be made which again as I said is impossible because the `create()` function was called earlier!

Comment: Again, there is no call to `utility`. Please provide the exact error message.

Answer (score 1):

> but if it was undefined how did it even make a call to window.parent.create() ?

The arguments are processed *before* the function is called (after all, the program needs to know the function's arguments). This is why it's failing on `window.parent.utility.getId()` instead of `window.parent.create()`, the `.getId()` is running first.

I'd bet that if you replaced `window.parent.utility.getId()` with a string literal you'd see the failure happen on the `.create()` call instead.

**Edit** as pointed out by Bergi below technically the program *is* accessing `window.parent.create` first, which will return `undefined`. This value doesn't matter until after the arguments are processed and it tries to call the value as a function. The `getId()` function fails before this happens, which is why you are seeing this specific error.

Comment: Still, the `create` property on `window.parent` is accessed *before* the argument expressions are evaluated, even if the call to the method happens afterwards.

Comment: @Bergi sure but it's `undefined` when accessed, which doesn't matter until it's called. I'll update my answer to be more accurate though, thanks!

Comment: If `window.parent` is `undefined`, it throws before the arguments are evaluated. If `.create` is `undefined`, it evaluates the arguments and then complains that it's not a function. So we can conclude that `window.parent` is not `undefined`, but either `.utility` or `.getId` are.

Comment: @Bergi you're absolutely right, if `window.parent` were `undefined` it would fail *before* the args were processed ("Cannot access property 'create' of undefined"). So `window.parent` must be set to *something*, just not what OP is expecting it to be

Comment: @SimonR there is still one problem whether it is like you said or not. I mentioned that it fails inside `window.parent.utility.getId()` but also on some occasions `window.parent.create()` fails also, which means that it didn't fail on the evaluation of the arguments! This is why I keep thinking if like there is some racing condition or racing action that is making something `undefined`